# How to search for names of users on social media websites via scraping in php

Tags: php, screen-scraping

**Main Question**

I want to have an `input` element , where I can type `user name` and when I hit enter, the back end `script` of `php` should search that name on different `social media sites` and give me the result that matches that `name`.

My client asks me to give him such a functionality so that when he search for different `names` of users he should get some result from websites *like* `social media sites` or may be `other`.

I think it seems like `scraping` websites for some information, may be I'm `wrong`.

I have written the following script for my website to **scrape** it.

```
<?php   



$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$DOM = new DOMDocument;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$elements = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');


foreach ($elements as $element) {

    echo "<div style = 'margin-left:10px;'>".$element->nodeValue.'</div><br>';
    
}
```

?>

I'm getting the results as all `anchors` on that page.

How can I search for `specific names` across `social media` sites?

Is there any `api` etc, if so please give me your precious response, if `no` then let me know about the `alternative` to achieve success in this task, because it is really *important* and need to be done.

I don't know either it is `legal` or not , so pardon me for that.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: First you need Google search api then make a call to get the google results then from YOUR social media site array extract pages like facebook,twitter,linkedin then match the user name with results array title if match 80% to 100% then you put this weblink into deep search and collect all the info on page like image,location and whatever is available, with this info you create a result page and serve it as your result below to input box where client first wrote the name. This includes deep knowledge of multi-curl and powerful server, Caution.. Your ip might get blacklisted by social website.

Comment: Can you give me any useful link what should I study, any article etc, because I searched a lot , but did't found any related information

Comment: so it's not legal then , If my ip get blacklisted , right ?

Comment: that is upto the Website if they want to blacklist or not but scrapping itself is not legal is many country so don't worry about it. Client is GOD, if he asks then make it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Long Answer
First you need to buy the Google search API
[Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

It will give you json data as links and other details

Now you might have an array of Web links something like this

```
$socialMedia = array('facebook.com','twitter.com','lnkedin.com');
```

Now with the result that Google gave to you you need to find all the links that are in your $socialMedia array.

After that you need to to create a curl request to the link and extract the information from that web page, Information like
Name
Location
Image
Age
etc

Then this info will be an array like property, Just server this multi-dy array to the client

Things you need to know
Multi curl function
So many ip's

So many ips coz if the social media website see that you are making so many request to there website they will restrict your Server IP for a while or may be permanently so if you switch the ip on every request it will be fine.

For the **scraping** i suggest use the open source php library
[Php Scraping Library](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/)

By this you can achieve your desired result

**Edit**

Don't try to scrape Google search, You will get blacklisted within a minute and then you need to fill up captcha for all search on google for a week,a month not sure how that google algo works but it's nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for this information , 
Google search api is free for some requests as it says this _Custom Search JSON API provides 100 search queries per day for free_.

what If I don't buy this first, I want to test it for some requests and then buy it, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes you can try that first 100 for any day is free. also If you're satisfied with my answer mark is as accepted, :)

Comment: okay, I'll, but I want to ask something
can I do this task with the library that you have mentioned `Php scraping library` ? I mean without google search api ?

Comment: read more about the library here https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom also make sure to check the examples so get the basic idea

Comment: Can you please move this comments to chat, I want to ask something more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201009/discussion-between-blackxero-and-contributor).